# How can @ContextSingletons be overridden for testing with RoboGuice?

Tags: android, testing, dependency-injection, roboguice

I'm trying to override a couple of injections for testing with a specific test module. This works fine as is for real singletons like so:

```
...custom module...
bind(SomeClass.class).toInstance(instanceOfMockedClass);
...
```

Now this imposes problems when `ContextSingletons` need to be overwritten. Doing the same like above obviously injects the same instance for all contexts (services, activities), where a separate instance would have been correct. I tried to wrap my head around the `ContextScopedProvider` but couldn't find a way to actually use this in a `bind(...).toProvider(...)` construct, as this class itself does not implement Guice's `Provider<T>` interface.

How can this be achieved?

(also asked on https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/roboguice/MnWGrHFDOsQ)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An alternate way to write that for a regular singleton would be something like this

`bind(SomeClass.class).toProvider(SomeClassProvider.class).in(Singleton.class);`

If you do it that way, you don't need to have the instance available at the time of the binding, which while fine for a Singleton, obviously won't work for a ContextSingleton since there's no context yet.

You can use the same kind of binding for a ContextSingleton:

`bind(SomeClass.class).toProvider(SomeClassProvider.class).in(ContextSingleton.class);`

Now, all the instances of SomeClass that RoboGuice injects for you will be properly scoped, whether Singleton or ContextSingleton.

Comment: Now, the problem is that I need to determine for what context the injection is triggered. My use case is that I have a service and an activity that should both inject roboguice's EventManager (which I want to override for different reasons). So I need to ensure that I have exactly one overriden instance for each context available, otherwise the event mechanism between the components would no longer work (if each component gets its own instance) or events I throw in the activity context also reach the service context, which is something I don't want.

Comment: As long as you bind each instance of your overridden EventManager using a ContextSingleton, each context should get its own EventManager.  Be aware: if you're mixing bindings and annotations, bindings will always take precedence and annotations will be ignored.  So if you have a @ContextSingleton annotation but you write a `bind(X.class).toProvider(Y.class);`, X will NO LONGER be a ContextSingleton, even though it has a @ContextSingleton annotation.

Comment: So are you saying that `bind(SomeClass.class).toProvider(SomeClassProvider.class).in(ContextSingleton.class);` should exactly do the magic, i.e. it only lets `SomeClassProvider` create one instance per `Context`? If yes, then this is the answer I'm looking for :)